# How does $\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) - 2x) = 0$ imply that $\lim_{y \to \infty} (g(y) - \frac{y}{2}) = 0$ without doing a calculation?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

**The original function is**

> $f(x) = \sqrt{4x^2 + 1}$ for $x \in [0,\infty)$

**and the inverse is**

> $g(y)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

we use the limit composition.

$$\lim_{x\to\color{red}{+\infty}}(f(x)-2x)=0$$

and
$$\lim_{y\to +\infty}g(y)=\color{red}{+\infty}$$

$$\implies$$

$$\lim_{y\to+\infty}(f(g(y))-2g(y))=0$$

but

$$f(g(y))-2g(y)=2(\frac y2-g(y))$$